# Failed to pull image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/..." OpenShift CRC

Tags: openshift, devops, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

I am trying to install a sample application using the git option in OpenShift 4.7.2 (CodeReady containers 1.24) and I keep getting the below error while openshift tries to build the image to be deployed.

```
Failed to pull image 
"image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/employee-ecosys/person-service:latest": rpc error: 
code = Unknown 
desc = Error reading manifest latest in image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/employee-ecosys/person-service: 
manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

[image: Snapshot of the events streamed in the build logs]

The application person-service is a simple crud application build using spring-boot and uses in-memory h2 as its database. [Github repo is here](https://github.com/adnanmamajiwala/demo-person-service/tree/ocp)

Answer (score 1):

Some checks to perform:
Are the image registry pods running?

```
oc get pods -n openshift-image-registry
```

Is your specific image created?

```
oc get images | grep "person-service"
```

Do you get any images?

```
oc get images
```

"latest" is kind of a special tag. You should never manually tag an image as "latest". Openshift will consider the "latest" tag to be the newest image, regardless of what tag it has.

I am not familiar with the git deploy method. I have personally very little experience with any s2i builds. I normally use a git repo for the openshift/kubernetes resources and a git repo for the code (they can be the same but separated in the tree by folder structure) and use a pipeline or manually build the image and push it to a registry somewhere and then let openshift pull it from there.